# Get-childitem attribute shorthand syntax options

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, get-childitem

Starting with Powershell v3.0, the following syntax is possible for `Get-ChildItem`:

```
dir -af
```

Which applies certain attribute selection criteria. By experiment, I found that it means:

```
dir -File
```

Which is the same as this:

```
dir -Attributes !Directory
```

Is there any official reference on attribute shorthand syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's specified on MSDN:

- [Get-ChildItem for FileSystem (PowerShell 3.0)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847897%28v=wps.620%29.aspx)

Search for `af` on the page, second match:

```
Directory d, ad
File af
Hidden h, ah
ReadOnly ar
System as
```

Can also get it via `Get-Help dir -full`, see `Notes` section, before `Example 1`.

Answer (score 1):

I have PowerShell v4 and these Parameter aliases are listed in the built-in help file, this is how I saw them

```
Help Get-ChildItem -full
```

Scroll down...

Notes .....

```
 Get-ChildItem Alias Reference:
        ---------------------------------
        Get-ChildItem     dir
        Directory         d, ad
        File              af
        Hidden            h, ah
        ReadOnly          ar
        System            as
```

Being aliases, you need to introduce them with the - (minus sign)

```
Get-ChildItem c:\ -ad -Force
```

Note 1: I found that 'ad' lists only the directories, whereas 'd' would also list files.

Note 2: I find that -force is useful especially when looking for hidden files or folders.